# FireEvent.click TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm using React Test Library and I have a a tag nested in a bunch of dome elements. I have a test id on it and I can see its debugging out with the correct node. But when I run my test.

```
import { render, cleanup } from '@testing-library/react';

test('bla', () => {
  const { fireEvent, getByTestId, debug } = render(
    <Group>
      <Menu items={items} />
    </Group>
  );

  const viewMore = getByTestId('button');
  console.log('viewMore = ', viewMore);
  // debug(viewMore);
  fireEvent.click(viewMore, {});
});
```

I get the following error.

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
> ```

Why would this tell me Cannot read property 'click' ?

My a tag with class of button is inside of my menu component that gets rendered inside Group.

Here is a stripped down version of what **viewMore** is returning.

```
 viewMore =  HTMLAnchorElement {
        '__reactInternalInstance$6ct8li9ulz6': 
         FiberNode {
           tag: 5,
           key: null,
           elementType: 'a',
           type: 'a',
           stateNode: [Circular],
           return: 
            FiberNode {
              tag: 5,
              key: null,
              elementType: 'div',
              type: 'div'},
           child: null,
           sibling: null,
           index: 1,
           ref: null,
           pendingProps: 
            { href: '#',
              className: 'button',
              'data-testid': 'button',
              onClick: [Function: action],
              children: 'VIEW MORE...' },
           memoizedProps: 
            { href: '#',
              className: 'button',
              'data-testid': 'button',
              onClick: [Function: action],
              children: 'VIEW MORE...' }
        '__reactEventHandlers$6ct8li9ulz6': 
         { href: '#',
           className: 'a-tag',
           'data-testid': 'button',
           onClick: [Function: action],
           children: 'VIEW MORE...' } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fireEvent` doesn't come from `render` you need to import it from RTL:

```js
import { fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react'
```